# How to output 'Favourites/Likes' list in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have implemented a like/favourite function in my application, where a user can favourite a Charity - this is then stored in a table in my database - which is working reasonably well.

How would I go about outputting the users favourites list to them on their profile page?

Profile View (Where I want to output):

```
<div class="favourite_section">

<div class="col-md-5 pull-right">

  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">

      <a href="#" class="pull-right"> Edit </a>

        <h3 class="panel-title"> Your Favourites </h3>

     </div>

      <div class="panel-body">

        <!-- Output users' favourites. -->

          <h4>  </h4>

      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Like Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Like;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LikeController extends Controller
{
public function likePost($id)
{
    $this->handleLike('App\charity', $id);
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function handleLike($type, $id)
{
    $existing_like = Like::withTrashed()->whereCharityImg($type)->whereCharityDesc($type)->whereCharityName($type)->whereCharityId($id)->whereUserId(Auth::id())->whereId($id)->first();
    if (is_null($existing_like))
    {
        Like::create([
            'id'       => $id,
            'user_id'   => Auth::id(),
            'charity_id' => $id,
            'charity_name' => $type,
            'charity_desc' => $type,
            'charity_img' => $type
        ]);

    } 
    else
    {
        if (is_null($existing_like->deleted_at))
        {
            $existing_like->delete();
        }

        else
        {
            $existing_like->restore();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're able to retrieve the currently logged in user with [Laravel's Authentication Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) or, if you prefer using helpers, `auth()->user()`. In a similar vein, you can do `Auth::id()` to skip the object and get the user's id directly. In your controller, you'll want to query the Like model where the user_id of the Like is equal to the user id of the logged in user:

```
$likes = Like::whereUserId(Auth::id())->get();
```

This will return a collection of likes which should be passed to the view from the controller, like so:

```
return view('profile', compact('likes'));
```

Replace 'profile' with whatever the view file for the profile page is. Then in the Blade template, you'll have access to a $likes variable, which you can iterate over:

```
@foreach($likes as $like)
  // Do what you want with each like
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is called many to many relationship.

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Laravel makes it easy. You should write a method to you User model. 
Something like:

```
public function favourites() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Charity', '[Like model table name]', 'user_id', 'charity_id');
}
```

You then can use it like: `$user->favourites` and it will return collection of favourite charities.

You can read docs if you want.